# Partition function of one-dimensional harmonic oscillator of non-interacting fermions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, entropy

[image: this was the question asked in the entrance exam of Tata institute of fundamental research]

The energy per oscillator of an isolated system of large number of non interacting fermions in one dimensional harmonic oscillator is $5hv/4$ then Entropy per oscillator is?